# Trying to use boost filesystem. cannot find -lboost_system

Tags: windows, boost, codeblocks

I have looked through the file library for boost and it does have filesystem but it doesn't have anything for system. However, when I run the code without including system, I get an error saying filesystem needs the boost system to run properly. I am running Code::Blocks 10.05 with a GNU GCC compiler. I have tried including -lboost_system in the links for my project but it couldn't find system either. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I found System in another folder called boost but I don't know how to build it

Comment: Go to boost.org and see "getting started" manual.

Comment: I am following the instructions but it says that I should have a folder called lib as well as a folder called libs. I only have libs. I have been trying to find something on google about this but it has not been working out very well so far; How do I get lib?

Comment: I don't see where "lib" is mentioned on boost site. After you build boost, you can copy the libraries to whatever directory you want, but first build them. See details here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#invoke-b2

Comment: @Igor R. Ok, now I am almost there, I am trying to invoke b2, I have this error: [link](http://i.imgur.com/nfylF.png)

Comment: you wrote you used gcc, so I thought you're under Linux. If you use MinGW or Cygwin -- you should read this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: @Igor R.When I run b2 as according to the turorial, where do I run it from and which folder do I give it as the build-directory?

Comment: cd to the directory where you unpacked boost, invoke b2 there, don't set build-directory (leave it default).

Comment: @Igor R.I went to the bin directory that had b2.exe and bjam.exe in it which I think is where I unpacked it. Then, I ran b2 ^ then build-dir="C:\boost_1_52_0\tools\build\v2 I got an error saying no toolsets are configured then one saying to set it using "toolset=xxxx" Also, no jamfile in current directory so when I ran that like this: toolset=gcc like the tutorial said to, it gave me an error saying no command provided, default command 'g++' not found

Comment: Again: gcc is a *linux* toolset. C:\ is non-linux path. What is your platform?

Comment: @Igor R. im running windows 8 with codeblocks, with MinGW. the tutorial said that I should use the gcc code if im using MinGW

Comment: So you're trying to build for MinGW under Windows command prompt? Documentation says it's possible, but I never tried such an approach (I use MSys). Try setting MINGWDIR environment variable and adding this path to PATH as well.

Comment: @Igor R., sorry it took so long to respond, finals week :( Is MINGWDIR evironment variable in Codeblocks or is that something related to my entire computer? Also, how do I change it?